# how is code select and play Audio Service flutter? I want to select and play

Tags: android, flutter, audio, service

How is code select and play Audio Service flutter? I want to select the track and play the track. So I want to go to another track.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.